# ELK for spring boot application using docker - performance issues

Tags: docker, logstash, docker-compose, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

We are using ELK for logging in our spring application using docker setup. I have configured log stash to read the log file from a given path(where the application generates the logs) and pass it to elastic search. The initial setup works fine and all the logs are passed to kibana instantly. However, as the size of the logs increase (or some form of application logging happens), the response time for application increases exponentially and ultimately brings down the application and everything within the docker network.

Logstash conf file:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "java"
    path => ["/logs/application.log"]
  }
filter {

  multiline {   
      pattern => "^%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME}.*"
      negate => "true"
      what => "previous"
      periodic_flush => false
    }
  if [message] =~ "\tat" {
    grok {
      match => ["message", "^(\tat)"]
      add_tag => ["stacktrace"]
    }
  }
  grok {
    match => [ "message", 
               "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME})  %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{NUMBER:pid} --- \[(?<thread>[A-Za-z0-9-]+)\] [A-Za-z0-9.]*\.(?<class>[A-Za-z0-9#_]+)\s*:\s+(?<logmessage>.*)",
               "message",
               "(?<timestamp>%{YEAR}-%{MONTHNUM}-%{MONTHDAY} %{TIME})  %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{NUMBER:pid} --- .+? :\s+(?<logmessage>.*)"
             ]
  }

  #Parsing out timestamps which are in timestamp field thanks to previous grok section
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ]
  }
}
output {
  # Sending properly parsed log events to elasticsearch
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] // elastic search is the name if the service in docker-compose file for elk
}
}}
```

Logstash Docker file:

```
FROM logstash
ADD config/logstash.conf /tmp/config/logstash.conf 
Volume $HOME/Documents/logs /logs
RUN touch /tmp/config/logstash.conf
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["logstash", "agent","-v","-f","/tmp/config/logstash.conf"]
```

docker compose for ELK:

```
version: '2'
services:
 elasticsearch:
  image: elasticsearch:2.3.3
  command: elasticsearch -Des.network.host=0.0.0.0
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
    - "9300:9300"
  networks:
    - elk
 logstash:
  build: image/logstash
  volumes:
    - $HOME/Documents/logs:/logs
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  networks:
    - elk
 kibana:
  image: kibana:4.5.1
  ports:
    - "5601:5601"
  networks:
    - elk

networks:
  elk:
```

Note: My spring-boot application and elk are on different networks. The performance issue remains same even if they are on same container.

Is this a performance issue because of the continuous writing/polling of a log file which is causing read/write lock issues?

Comment: Just to confirm, this problem symptoms occur at the application, but do not arise when you don't have the elk stack component?

Comment: Also assuming you are on a linux host, try using `docker stats $(docker ps | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -v NAMES)` to watch the resource usage of your various containers, that may help diagnose the problem

Comment: There is no performance issue when there is no ELK component involved.
I will check the stats to see the resource usage

Comment: @SwethaV Where are you at with this issue?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I would suggest switching to Filebeat for forwarding the logs to a Logstash cluster.

Comment: What are you using for logging in spring? I would suggest to take a look at log4j 2 since they provide asynchronous logging, which means your application won't slow down only because of logging!